# Why RxCocoa didn't provide subscribe for UILabel's text change?

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

RxCocoa provide subscribe for `UITextField` and `UITextView` text change:

```swift
UITextField().rx.text.orEmpty.changed
    .subscribe { text in
        print(text)
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

UITextView().rx.text.changed.subscribe { t in
    print(t)
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But no convenience for `UILabel`:

```swift
UILabel().rx.text.subscribe ...
```

Why rxcocoa designed for this?

Comment: Because a user can enter text into a text field. The contents of a label is not user mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, the `text` method is a wrapper around the UIControl's `addTarget(:action:for:)` method. It turns that method into something that is Observable.

The `UILabel` type isn't derived from `UIControl` and so doesn't have an `addTarget(:action:for:)` method. You can't attach an `@IBAction` to a UILabel in normal UIKit, so you can't attach an Rx ControlProperty to a UILabel either.

And just like in UIKit, you don't need to observe changes to a UILabel because the only way it changes is if *your code* changed it. Just observe the thing that triggered the label to change instead.

---

It will help to understand if you look at the code... The `text` method is just a rename of the `value` method:

```
public var text: ControlProperty<String?> {
    value
}
```

and the `value` method is a ControlProperty that monitors the "default events".

```
    public var value: ControlProperty<String?> {
        return base.rx.controlPropertyWithDefaultEvents(
```

Looking at `controlPropertyWithDefaultEvents`, we can find out what the default events are:

```
internal func controlPropertyWithDefaultEvents<T>(
    editingEvents: UIControl.Event = [.allEditingEvents, .valueChanged],
    getter: @escaping (Base) -> T,
    setter: @escaping (Base, T) -> Void
    ) -> ControlProperty<T>
```